# Why "return names;" is get null?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have two arrays and two classes. I need to have an output of a name and age of a user, but i have a problem with "names" because of returning null. "Ages" is working fine. Where is my mistake?

```
public class Lesson4OOP {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Adam","Sara", "Mike" , "David"};
    int[] ages = {21, 25, 34, 16};
    User[] users = new User[names.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<users.length; i++){
        User u = new User();
        u.setName(names[i]);
        users[i] = u;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j<ages.length; j++){
        User a = new User();
        a.setAge(ages[j]);
        users[j] = a;
    }
    System.out.println(users[3].getName());
    System.out.println(users[3].getAge());
    }
}

public class User {
    String names;
    int ages;

    public void setName(String val){
        names = val;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return names;
    }
    public void setAge(int num){
        ages = num;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return ages;
    }
}
```

The output is :

> null
>
> 16

Comment: Why are you creating 8 users, 4 with names and 4 with ages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-assigning a new `User` in the second loop with `name` set to `null` by default. You should either re-use an existing `User` object, like this

```
for(int j = 0; j<ages.length; j++){
    users[j].setAge(ages[j]);
}
```

do both assignments in a single loop (since arrays have he same length)

```
for(int i = 0; i<users.length; i++){
    User u = new User();
    u.setName(names[i]);
    users[j].setAge(ages[i]);
    users[i] = u;
}
```

or add a constructor, and pass name and age to it:

```
for(int i = 0; i<users.length; i++){
    User u = new User(names[i], ages[i]);
}
```

If you allow setting `name` and `age` this way, you can make the class immutable, too:

```
public class User {
    final String name;
    final int age;
    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the semantics of the class User, isn't the age mutable in reality, so setters are needed, and class cannot be immutable?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have overriden the existing objects in the `users` array with your second iteration.

```
for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){ //array is named 'names'
    User u = new User();
    u.setName(names[i]);
    users[i] = u;
}

for(int j = 0; j<ages.length; j++){
    user[i].setAge(ages[j]); // using the existing object here
}
```

---

On the other side of it, I would assume you shall be having name to age mapping in terms of the number of users. Hence it should be safe to do something like :

```
if(names.length != ages.length) { 
    // input mismatch for ages and names ; do some action in this condition
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        users[i].setName(names[i]);
        users[i].setAge(ages[i])
    } 
}
```